# Cannot show image outside WEB-INF folder

Tags: jsp, servlets, web-inf

I have a folder
structure folder:
[image: structure folder]

I want to show images on index.jsp from img folder. But it won't show

So far I tried

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<jsp:include page="includes/header.jsp" />

    <h2 class="page-header">Home</h2>
    <base href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/" />


        <li><a href="${pageContext.request}/about">Home</a></li>
        <a href="../../resources/img/1.png">
   <img src="/resources/img/1.png" alt="logo">
   <img src="WEB-INF/views/img/1.png" alt="studenst">
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/img/1.png" />
<img src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/img/1.png" />
<h:graphicImage value="/resources/img/1.png" />
```

And this is my simple controller.

```
public class HomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public HomeServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String path = request.getServletPath();

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp");

        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
```

Why its not working?

If I place index.jsp outside web-inf folder (in web content), its working. But I want to place index.jsp inside web-inf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the directory path of the 1.png and then paste in the src (where u want to provide the image)

Comment: thanks for the answer. it works. i copied the location

 <img src="C:\Users\GG\eclipse-workspace\testweb\WebContent\img\1.png" value= alt="">

Thanks for your help, Sir.

Comment: You are always welcome. Can you click on the tick option near my answer so that  this answer is ticked as correct. The tick will turn green in color@vodka

Comment: Realize that you've now eliminated any chance of running this in a web server off of your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try with 
`<img src="<c:url value="/resources/img/1.png" />" />`

Comment: i already tried. its not working. but i already found the answer. it is 

 <img src="C:\Users\GG\eclipse-workspace\testweb\WebContent\img\1.png" value= alt="">


thanks for the answer.

Comment: @vodka The solution you're using is depending on your machine's file system (you're using absolute path to files) and that's rarely acceptable. You can check [this](https://github.com/Martin-BG/SoftUni-Java-Web-Development-Basics-Jan-2019/tree/master/06.%20Java%20EE%20-%20Java%20Server%20Pages/Exercise/Me%20Tube) demo project for details how to link static resources in JSP file.

Comment: okay. thanks for provide the link demo project, i will learn from there. but theres no images there. for linking the bootstrap or js, it works.

Comment: @vodka The principle of linking static resources in JSP no mater of the type (js, css, jpg and so on) is the same. In the project I gave link to, added `img` folder and a `picure.jpg` file to it can be linked with `<img src="<c:url value="/resources/img/picture.jpg" />" />` in JSP file and will display correctly in browser. Please check your project setup and compare it with the demo project.